# Visual Studio and MySQL

Tags: mysql, visual-studio

I have been using Microsoft Visual Web Developer 2008 Express Edition.  Originally, I made a website with a MySQL back-end.  Then I discovered the .Net web authentication, and moved to MS Access as I could, with some modification, make the web authentication work (but not all the features).  For a future release of my site, I moved to MS SQL as it supported all of the features of the .Net web authentication.  However, my host does not support MS SQL, my host supports MS Access and MySQL.

If I get Visual Studio 2008 Standard, with it have better integration with MySQL, to the point that all features of web authentication and using the development environment to make changes to the database are supported?  Are there thrid-party tools or modifications that I can make to get things to that level of integration?

Or, do I have to move to a host that supports MS SQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We run a .NET environment here but using MySQL as our backend (though our software is applications, not web apps).

The MySql Net Connector is *basically* the MySQL version of the System.Data namespace in .NET (with nearly identical functionality/naming except for the MySql prefixes). So, as far as I have seen while working with it, anything that you can do via those namespaces, you can do via the connector.

As for IDE integration, I don't know. I use [MySql Administrator](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/gui-tools/5.0.html) and [SQLYog](http://webyog.com/en/downloads.php) to manage/work with the db.

Answer (score 2):

[You could try MySQL's .NET connector, though it's only a development version](http://www.mysql.com/products/connector/net/)

Comment: The page you link to provides a link to the 1.0 version of the connector. Be sure to check the left side of the page after clicking the Download link to select a more recent version (they are up to version 6.0 as of this writing).